# PHP/Laravel - How to initiate a class with it's dependencies in a trait

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use a method from a class that I have in one trait. The class that I need looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\Content\ContentInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Corcel\Post;
use EllipseSynergie\ApiResponse\Laravel\Response;
use App\Transformers\IndexTransformer;

class ImportController extends Controller
{
    private $indexable;

    function __construct(Response $response, ContentInterface $contentInterface)
    {
        $this->indexable = \Config::get('middleton.wp.content.indexable_types');
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->contentInterface = $contentInterface;

    }

    public function updateOrCreateInventory($remoteId)
    {
       $this->contentInterface->updateOrCreateInventory($remoteId);
    }
}
```

I would like to use the `updateOrCreateInventory` method in a trait that I have or to be more specific in it's method :

```
namespace App\Libraries\Content;

use App\Inventory;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

use App\Http\Controllers\ImportController;

trait SupplementaryFormatter
{

    private static function getInventoryUrl($id)
    {
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
           $inventory = Inventory::where('remote_id', $id)->first();

           if(!$inventory) {
              ImportController::updateOrCreateInventory($id);
           } else {
              return  '/' . $inventory->url;
           }
        }
        return $id;
     }
 }
```

But, I am not sure how can I initiate the class in the trait with it's dependencies, because when I import the `Response` and `ContentInterface` class to a trait and try to pass it to the constructor of the `ImportController` class, like so:

```
(new ImportController(new Response, new ImportController))->updateOrCreateInventory($id);
```

I get an error that I am not passing dependencies to `Response` and `ImportController`. How can I make this work?

Comment: Does `ImportController` uses `SupplementaryFormatter` trait?

Comment: No, it is not using it, but the ```ContentStorage``` that implements ```ContentInterface``` that is being called from the ```ImportController``` uses it. Which means I could use the method ```updateOrCreateInventory``` directly from the ```ContentStorage``` class, just don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `app()->make()`?

If not, try it:

```
if(!$inventory) {
    $controller = app()->make(ImportController::class);
    $controller->updateOrCreateInventory($id);
} else {
   return  '/' . $inventory->url;
}
```

Also, I don't think you are doing it in the right way. I think you should move the function `updateOrCreateInventory` to some service and in your trait create a instance of this service.